# VSTS show all open items across all projects

Tags: azure-devops

Our company currently has about 10 active projects and 5 programmers.
My manager wants a weekly update on all open items, just a list of them.
I only need the list for our organization, not across multiple organizations.

I can see all open items assigned to me, but I cannot seem to figure out a way to see all open items across all projects.

Is there a way to do this without having to go to all 10 projects then manually compile this list?

It is looking like we have perhaps set stuff up less than optimally.
Is is perhaps better to use less projects and group work differently?

Joe

Hmmm...reading this:

> **When to add another project** In general, we recommend that you use a single project to support your organization or enterprise. A single
>   project minimizes the maintenance of administrative tasks and allows
>   full flexibility to cross-link objects.

from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/projects/about-projects?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav

makes me think we may have setup or organization wrong.  It would have been great if this was made a bit clearer in the documentation.  This is the first I have seen this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a query and check the "Query across projects" checkbox:

For example, this query give you all the bugs in all projects with state "In Progress":
[image]

You can save the query and display the results on the dashboard or export to Excel with [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=blueprint.vsts-open-work-items-in-excel) extension.

Comment: wow....I simply did NOT see that checkbox.  That would do it.  Thank you.

Comment: Any idea on how to know which project?  Project Name does not seem to be one of the column options...

Comment: Found it....it is called 'Team Project' -- for some reason if you type project it did not find it.  Maybe only searches first words.